# How should unapplied method references be handled?

Tags: language-design, object-oriented

Several OO languages allow you to grab unapplied method references.

Some, such as Kotlin or Python, have them accessible from the class itself and just append `self` onto the front of the argument list.

```kotlin
class IntWrapper(private val x: Int) {
  fun adding(other: IntWrapper) = IntWrapper(x + other.x)
}

val additionFunc: (IntWrapper, IntWrapper) -> IntWrapper = IntWrapper::adding
```

<sup>Excuse the terrible example, I can't think of any practical one off the top of my head.</sup>

JavaScript handles this notoriously poorly, due to the weird rules around `this`:

```js
class NumberWrapper {
  constructor(x) { this.x = x; }
  adding(other) { return new NumberWrapper(this.x + other.x); }
}

const additionFunc = NumberWrapper.prototype.adding;
let fifteen = additionFunc.apply(new NumberWrapper(5), [new NumberWrapper(10)]);
// OR
const addFive = additionFunc.bind(new NumberWrapper(5));
fifteen = addFive(new NumberWrapper(10));
```

Swift handles this in a way I don't think I've seen before, modelling unapplied references as currying in a way that's not otherwise common in the language.

```swift
// Example method call, for comparison
let x = 1.0
_ = x.addingProduct(2.0, 3.0)

// Now, for the unapplied reference:
let fma: (Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double = Double.addingProduct
// what the heck is that type signature?
```

Some languages, like C#, don't provide any mechanism for this, and you have to explicitly write out `x => x.Foo()`.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to each approach? What other approaches exist?

Answer (score 2):

C++ has `std::mem_fun()` to turn a pointer-to-member-function into a function object:

```
class IntWrapper {
    int x;
public:
    IntWrapper(int x): x(x) {}
    IntWrapper adding(const IntWrapper& other) {
        return {x + other.x};
    }
};

auto additionFunc = std::mem_fun(&IntWrapper::adding);
auto three = additionFunc(IntWrapper(1), IntWrapper(2));
```

You can use the pointer-to-member-function itself instead of using `std::mem_fun()`, but the syntax is rather awful:

```
auto additionFunc = &IntWrapper::adding;
auto three = (IntWrapper(1).*additionFunc)(IntWrapper(2));
```

There is `std::bind()` as well to do currying. But all that results in objects that act like regular functions: you call them with some parameters, and a value comes out. What happens in your Swift example:

```
let fma: (Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double = Double.addingProduct
// what the heck is that type signature?
```

This is not a function that returns a value, but you are declaring a function that takes a `Double` and returns another function that has the signature `(Double, Double) -> Double`. So the call `fma(1.0)` returns a function that takes two parameters and that evaluates `Double(1.0).addingProduct(/* those parameters */)`; `fma(1.0)(2.0, 3.0)` is then equivalent to `Double(1.0).addingProduct(2.0, 3.0)`.

In C++ you could write:

```
auto fma(double z) {
    return [z](double x, double y) {
        return std::fma(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

And call it like `fma(1.0)(2.0, 3.0)` as well. Swift's syntax doesn't use lambda expressions, it's more like the pointer-to-member function from above, but with the benefit that you can call it the same way as a normal function, whereas C++ needs that special syntax.

I don't think Swift has any benefits for flexibility or performance, but it definitely is shorter to write.

Something I don't see though is a way to make this generic in Swift; you can't write:

```
let fma<T>: (T) -> (T, T) -> T = T.addingProduct
```

Whereas in C++ you could write:

```
auto fma = [](auto z) {
    return [z](auto x, auto y) {
        return std::fma(x, y, z);
    }
};
```